# How can I open a file on my mac from my pi using python?

Tags: python, macos, raspberry-pi3

I am writing a small program onto my Raspberry Pi3 (on Python3), that controls access to a room. If the user inputs 2 correct forms of ID (example pin and correct card swipe) then the door will open, but I want to send a message to alert me if someone's access is denied. I was thinking doing this by connecting to my Mac via ssh from my pi and then opening some sort of warning message on my mac.

so I created a small GUI file named `Warning.py` that is saved on my desktop.

I need to run `os.system('python3 ~/Desktop/Warning.py')`.

Any idea how I can run that on my Mac from my Pi?

Answer (score 0):

Use ssh. You can connect, run a command, and then quit. You could put a line in your python script on your PI like this:

```
os.system('ssh <mac username>@<mac address> \" python3 ~/Desktop/Warning.py\"')
```

If you use RSA keys for authentication, the PI will connect without a prompt for authentication, and run the command as `<mac username>`. This will however print the output to the PI, not to the Mac, but I think you can cause a change in the filesystem that can be tested periodically for, by something like a cron job.